# How can I use an Or inside of an IF statement in C#?

Tags: c#

I am trying to create an if statement that will perform an action if any of the conditions are true. The items I need to test are the text values of eight textboxes. What I have right now is the following and the error it gives me says "Operator '||' cannot be applied to operands of type 'string' and 'string'".

```
if (textbox1.text = "" || textbox2.text = "" || ...... and so on)
```

If anyone knows a how I am supposed to be wording this if statement or an easy way to check to see if a .ini file at a known location exists. Either would work for me.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You need to use the equality operator `==` not the assignment `=`.

```
if (textbox1.text == "" || textbox2.text == "" || ...... and so on)
```

Your `textbox1.text = ""` sets the value of `textbox1.text` to an empty string, and returns this as the result of the assignment. You are therefore attempting to use a boolean or (`||`) on two strings.

Answer (score 3):

In C#, if you are checking if a value is equal - you need to use double equal sign.

Your code should look like this:

```
if (textbox1.text == "" || textbox2.text == "" || ...... and so on)
```

Answer (score 2):

`String.IsNullOrEmpty()` will return a boolean for you:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorempty.aspx

..and, like others have said, use "==" for testing equality.

Answer (score 1):

```
textbox1.text == "" ||
```

Note the DOUBLE = sign.

as written, your question would evaluate by first assigning empty string to each variable then applying the OR to those, so by the time the boolean is evaluated it looks like

```
if ("" || "" || "" ... etc)
```

and the OR operator doesn't work on strings.  Note that if you are not careful, then you'll quietly break this rule.

`if (x = true || y = false)` evaluates to `if (true || false)`, and won't give you such a timely compiler warning

Answer (score 1):

System.IO.File.Exists(path), returns a boolean

Comment: How is this in any way relevant to the question?

Comment: The last bit of the question: "...or an easy way to check to see if a .ini file at a known location exists."